# Got Null reference error with Moq and return an IList

Tags: c#, moq

I changed one of an interface methods return type from `IEnumerable` to `IList`, and then I got a Null reference error on my testing code.

If I revert my changes, it works fine.

My testing code use `Moq` library, after some inspection, I found the default behavior for `IEnumerable` and `IList` is different.

So I created an example project to illustrate my question: https://github.com/dawncold/MoqWithIList

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do?

Comment: "Why authors of a library done something in a particular way" is generally off-topic on SO as such questions are unlikely to provide authoritative answer and discussion around what reason could be there is not welcome on SO. You get better result by either asking more specific question why it is a problem for you or just go and check source code to see if reason is written out there.

Comment: @Nkosi I created an example, https://github.com/dawncold/MoqWithIList

Comment: [Known issue](https://github.com/moq/moq4/issues/330) with various ways to avoid it.

Comment: Your code should be in the question, not simply linked-to off-site.